# Document Class (or Alternative Solution) for Documenting Programming Code

Tags: document-classes, documentclass-writing, documentation

Different from writing a report or thesis involving code, I have the goal of producing a transcription of a C++ solution involving many projects with many `.h` and `.cpp` files. Furthermore, this document I am trying to produce will have a focus on the mathematical equations.

So far, I am giving each project a chapter, each file a section and each function a subsection, using `\begin{chapter}{Project}`, etc.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a document class appropriate for this undertaking?
2. If not, has anyone done this before, and what is the best method you've found?
3. If no one has done this before, what ideas do you all have?
4. At the furthest extreme, would I have to create a new document class?

As a side question, I am using TeXmaker. Any idea how to get `\begin{section}{File.cpp}` to appear in the structure pane?

Comment: Have a look at the [listings](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) and [minted](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) packages. They are both exceptionally good for code highlighting. My preference is to use `listings` and, in particular, the `\lstinputlisting` command to directly include source from an external file.

Comment: See if your university has a specific document class or template for LaTeX.  Otherwise, start with book,cls and get the university requirements.

Comment: The `ltxdoc` documentclass is set up for documenting style packages, and may (or not) be adaptable to your need.  The `numberedblock` provides a way to typeset code blocks in the manner of numbered equations.

Comment: I suggest the `tcolorbox` `documentation` library if eye-candy is important.